# Indesign Script: Get first paragraph in textframe in each group

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

Using Indesign CS5.5, I have a vast collection of groups - all with an image and a textframe. The textframe has 3 paragraphs by default.

I need to get the text from the first paragraph of each textframe.

So far I have this:

```
var textboxes = app.activeDocument.groups.everyItem().textFrames;
for (i = 0; i <= textboxes.length; i++) { 
    if(textboxes[i] != 'undefined') {
        var product = textboxes[i].contents;
        $.writeln(product);
    }
}
```

This gives me ALL the text...I really need to get the first paragraph only OR filter it somehow by font size.

I've tried using `textboxes[i].paragraphs[0]`, but this returns the rather vague `Object Invalid`. It might be a specific group, but it's too vague for me to tell.

Is there a way to skip and continue if an object is invalid. AND is there perhaps a way to only look for text with a certain font size?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I find Indesign's scripting API documentation quite poor.

Comment: Have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467344/indesign-script-how-to-get-first-paragraph-in-threaded-text-frame ?

Comment: I did try bits of that, but not the `textContainers` - will try that.

Comment: I can't use access textContainers in app.activeDocument. I should point out that the textframes are all separate and not part of any continuous story.

Comment: the contents object might have more methods on it. Right now you're invoking toString implicitly

Comment: @jontro Does .contents invoke toString? I did try `.contents.paragraph` but that's not a recognised method or property I think.

Comment: try `typeof contents`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158145/discussion-between-jontro-and-funktion).

Answer (score 1):

Suggest to use:

```
var m1stParas = app.activeDocument.groups.everyItem().textFrames.everyItem().paragraphs[0];
```

which should return an array of paragraphs (each element is a 1st para of each TF from each group)

So you will have a set of text objects. Each `object.contents` is a string.

In case of error "invalid object" - has your doc possibly empty textFrames in some groups?

Jarek

Comment: Thanks @Jarek that looks very promising... will try it out.